# Error when interacting with smart contract

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I deployed following contract in remix.ethereum
0x932FC462d97e23E9fe8d5a1F085d9D611B892666

and hooked it up to my UI at
https://tewkenbak.github.io/tewken/  (this is a contract for testing)

Following things happened
1) in remix.ethereum i wasnt able to compile the contract - no errors 
2) i was able to deploy the contract to the mainnet
3) the contract doesnt give me any errors when interacting with it at
https://etherscan.io/address/0x932fc462d97e23e9fe8d5a1f085d9d611b892666#writeContract

4) when I try to interact with contract through my UI - above link i get following Error

[image: Error message when trying to interat through UI]

the same time I get NO error message in the console

Comment: "I get NO error message in the console" --- how do you check it? Have you switched to that extension?

Comment: i dont get an error message in the console

Comment: Could you send a failed transaction and provide the hash? thanks

Comment: I messed something up with the UI or abi it seems cause now i cant load things like (Cntract Balane etc) anymore and i ant interact with the contract through the UI anymore

Comment: earlier i plugged the UI to this contract with is exatly the same contract as the 1 I deployed and i get this error
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x3b2f911d41550123fbf902e9e7cc024d19f3dbd1ce7e012e0b432074fddb5311

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE

I just checked your source code, looks like you gave the wrong method name here and some other places:

```
if (walletMode === 'metamask') {
  contract.buy(masternode, {
    value: convertEthToWei(amount)
  }, function (e, r) {
    console.log(e, r)
  })
}
```

there is no buy function in the contract.

---

You gave the wrong abi, since there is no function named `buy` in your smart contract.

Comment: im using the abi of the contract

Comment: @bitconnect Let me know if I miss anything.

Comment: in my win.js file i have this function
    console.log("[fund] using masternode "+masternode);
    if (walletMode === 'metamask') {
      contract.buy(masternode, {
        value: convertEthToWei(amount)
      }, function (e, r) {
        console.log(e, r)
      })
    } else if (walletMode === 'web') {
      call(contractAddress, 'buy', [masternode], convertEthToWei(amount))
    }
  }

Comment: i see what you mean.
Is there an easy way to create the functions from the smart contract:
All i need in the UI is buy sell withdraw and that Balances show

Comment: or can i  rename the function in the smart contract?

Comment: I guess you only need to rename `buy` in your js code to `buyToken`?

Comment: What's the function name displayed in metamask?
Just like the image you provided above. You can see a `buy` icon over there.